# UITableView Alphabetizing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, alphabetical

I have a UITableView that is successfully populated from a database, put into a NSArray and every cell is clickable and performs the correct action when selected, however the list is out of alphabetical order. In order to sort them into alphabetical order, I use the following code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [buildings sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

The alphabetizing works correctly, however when some of the cells (in this example it was the first cell in the list) are clicked the app terminates with an uncaught exception:

```
'NSRangeException' '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I'd be happy to post more code excerpts, I am just unsure of what relevant information would be needed to help answer this question.

Edit:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger r = [indexPath row];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(infoInst != nil) {
        infoInst = nil;
    }
    infoInst = [[DirInfoListing alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirInfoListing" bundle:nil building:[self.listData objectAtIndex:r] map:mapUI];

    NSLog(@"infoInst building: %@", [self.listData objectAtIndex:r]);

    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"]){
        [self presentModalViewController:infoInst animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoInst animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the stack trace immediately before the error is thrown

```
2013-07-03 16:56:56.579 thestanforddaily[32907:1a303] Stack trace : (
    0   thestanforddaily                    0x002190d9 -[Directory     tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 457
    1   UIKit                               0x01ae871d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1164
    2   UIKit                               0x01ae8952 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x0237086d __NSFireDelayedPerform + 389
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02acd966 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x02acd407 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 551
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x02a307c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x02a2fdb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x02a2fccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    9   GraphicsServices                    0x0327b879 GSEventRunModal + 207
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x0327b93e GSEventRun + 114
    11  UIKit                               0x01a58a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
    12  thestanforddaily                    0x00002f4d main + 141
    13  thestanforddaily                    0x00002e75 start + 53
) 
2013-07-03 16:57:13.740 thestanforddaily[32907:1a303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2af9052 0x28e8d0a 0x2ae5db8 0x21cb0e 0x1b1e64e 0x1b1e941 0x1b3047d 0x1b3066f   0x1b3093b 0x1b313df 0x1b31986 0x1b315a4 0x219250 0x1ae871d 0x1ae8952 0x237086d 0x2acd966 0x2acd407 0x2a307c0 0x2a2fdb4 0x2a2fccb 0x327b879 0x327b93e 0x1a58a9b 0x2f4d 0x2e75)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Post the code that runs when the cell is selected (e.g. your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if you're handling it that way) and the lines of code where the exception occurred (which you can ascertain by inspecting the call stack in the console).

Comment: I have added the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code where the exception occurs on the line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:infoInst animated:YES]`. As far as I can discern, `infoInst` is not null in any way and the index value should be within the proper range.

Comment: That line doesn't access an array. Can you post the stack trace from that line onward? Maybe there's a clue in there.

Comment: @TimothyMoose Sorry about my ineptitude with using the debugger, but I hope I have added the correct stack trace to the question.

Comment: Your stack trace indicates out of bounds array access in `-[Directory     tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]`, but the line mentioned in the above comment doesn't access an array. Can you double check what line of code is throwing the exception? If you haven't already done so, add an Exception break point (in the Breakpoint Navigator, click "+" and then "Add Exception Breakpoint...").

Comment: The call stack suggests that you are in the middle of a timer action. Did you find out where exactly the error is thrown? Did you add an all-exceptions breakpoint?

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"infoInst building: %@", self.infoData);` and see what the output is.

Comment: @TimothyMoose I added an exception breakpoint which helped me to determine that there is a disagreement between two of my arrays. One which is downloaded from a web backend (NSData collection), and another which is alphabetized (NSArray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only array access I see in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is `[self.listData objectAtIndex:r]`. So it would seem your `listData` array isn't in sync with the table's data model. From the code you posted, the array `sortedArray` should correspond to the data model, so make sure `listData` and `sortedArray` are kept in sync or just have one array. If you still can't figure it out, please post your `UITableViewDataSource` methods as well as the methods where you set up your various array variables.

Comment: You area completely correct, my `listData` array is not in sync with the `sortedArray`. I am attempting to figure out a way that I can keep the two in sync. Thank you very much for your input

Comment: @VonKoob I noticed that you initially accepted my answer, then later accepted a different answer that did not work according to your comments. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I think I just accidentally clicked on another answers checkbox on mistake. The root of my problem was actually a mistake in a coworkers code which caused an array to look for an index outside of bounds. Thank you and sorry for the mistake on unselecting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [buildings count] <= 1 ? buildings : [buildings sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Unless you require `sortedArray` to be a different instance than `buildings`. Then you should change the statement accordingly.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion, however there was no change in functionality and the error still occurred. Some information about `buildings` is that `buildings` is filled with a custom object `building` that has several properties, one of which is the Name property that the array should be alphabetized by.